# Warn new mobile users not to ask questions as answers

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, new-users, not-an-answer

When a new user tries to post an answer, they are warned [not to ask questions as answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132759). The text of the warning is pretty good (although I think it could use some **ALL-CAPS BOLD** instead of subtle *italic*). Unfortunately, it is only shown to desktop users, not to mobile site users.

I think this is a major omission: for example, almost 2/3 of *Android Enthusiasts* traffic and about half of *Travel* traffic is mobile, per QuantCast. Perhaps not coincidentally, these two sites also get a disproportional number of questions posted as answers.

I don't know if the desktop slide-out warning is suitable for mobile web, but *some* form of it should be shown. Hopefully, with some all-caps bold text about not asking questions in the answer box.

Answer (score 1):

I think that part of the problem is the Ask Question link is too difficult to spot on mobile:
[image: Where is it again? Oh yeah, it's in the middle-top, in 3 letters…]
It needs to be more obvious. More conspicuous. Something like:

> **ASK QUESTION** *(a lot of empty space)* <sub>The other links</sub>

I don't think that the omission of a hard-to-spot warning would do much to stop non-answers that would have been posted with the warning there. Questions posted as answers are probably mostly from these:

- Help vampires that have been q-banned
- People who don't know how to post questions but do know how to post answers